# LD proxy in R - how to replace missing SNPs?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I have a list of SNP in one txt file that I want to extract from another txt file using R. This is not a problem when the SNPs match. But  I want to replace SNPs not found with SNPs in LD and I cant see how I do this. Anyone who knows?

I've tried looking at the [proxysnps package](https://github.com/slowkow/proxysnps) for R without any luck.

Comment: This question is too broad, and also a very simple task in genetics. `"tried looking at the proxysnps"` - add your code, and example data.

Comment: Where do you get the “SNPs in LD” from? Is this a separate file/table? If so, this is fairly trivial to solve by performing an antijoin with the LD SNP table.

Comment: You might consider asking your question (with more details) in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/